# Deletion/Updation of rows using Spark SQL

Tags: apache-spark-sql

I want to delete the existing row and to update with new row.
Can we delete or update rows using Spark SQL from database?

Answer (score 0):

Spark SQL does not support `UPDATE` statements yet.

However Hive does support `UPDATE`/`DELETE` statements (since version 0.14), but only on tables that support **transactions**, as mentioned in the [hive documentation](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+DML#LanguageManualDML-Update).

Comment: and what about delete?

Answer (score 0):

sparkR code

```
sc <- sparkR.init()
sqlContext <- sparkRSQL.init(sc)

#create R data frame

df <- data.frame(col= c("A","A","B","B"),des= c("a","b","b","c"))

#converting to spark dataframe

sdf <- createDataFrame( sqlContext, df)

registerTempTable(sdf, "sdf")

head(sql(sqlContext, "SQL QUERY"))
```

try  the corresponding sql query in it and execute it. Dont know whether it will support update statement.